# Build Xamarin Android project error MSB3073 with Jenkins on Mac

Tags: android, xamarin, jenkins, xamarin.android, mono

I am using Jenkins to build Xamarin Android project.

And I see error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mono-symbolicate:
>   line 6: exec: mono: not found
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2194,3):
>   error MSB3073: The command
>   ""/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mono-symbolicate"
>   store-symbols "bin/Release/com.companyname.preoject.apk.mSYM"
>   "obj/Release/android/assets"" exited with code 127.
>   [/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/project_test_android/Droid/Project.Droid.csproj]
>   Done Building Project
>   "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/project_test_android/Droid/Project.Droid.csproj"
>   (PackageForAndroid target(s)) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.

I found https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/81671/cant-archive-any-android-project but it doesn't help me.

my build command

```
/p:Configuration=Release /t:PackageForAndroid /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution. I just added /p:MonoSymbolArchive=False to my command line